# Sendgrid send mail error using java

Tags: java, email, smtp, sendgrid

```
public class SimpleMail {

private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "Myusername";
private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "Password";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   new SimpleMail().test();
}

public void test() throws Exception{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
    // uncomment for debugging infos to stdout     

    mailSession.setDebug(true);        

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    BodyPart part1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    part1.setText("This is multipart mail and u read part1......");

    BodyPart part2 = new MimeBodyPart();
    part2.setContent("<b>This is multipart mail and u read part2......</b>","text.html");

    multipart.addBodyPart(part1);
    multipart.addBodyPart(part2);

    message.setContent(multipart);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("aKrishiv@absinessware.com"));
    message.setSubject("This is the subject");
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("someone@somewhere.com"));

    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();`
```

Can some one help me i am trying to send mail using SMTP the above code is found [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Example)

While running the code on eclipse i got this error

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0 DEBUG: getProvider() returning
javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true Username: Myusername Password:
Mypassword DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP: trying
to connect to host "smtp.sendgrid.net", port 587, isSSL false
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.sendgrid.net, 587; timeout -1;
nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
connect at
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961) at
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367) at
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226) at
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175) at
SimpleMail.test(SimpleMail.java:53) at
SimpleMail.main(SimpleMail.java:14) Caused by:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at
java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at
com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
... 6 more #
```

Comment: I don't understand why if you set `props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");` the connection is trying to be established on port 587.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there was a connection failure when connecting to the mail server(host: smtp.sendgrid.net, port 587).

You should make sure that your can connect to smtp.sendgrid.net on your machine.
You can try this command on the machine which the test was run on to verify the network connection:

```
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587
```

On success, you may get something like I just got by running this command:

```
220 mi19 ESMTP service ready
```